# Matching legends for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I refer to section 12.2.4, exercise 1 in [Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/scales.html).

In the exercise, the following code is provided:

```
fwd <- subset(mpg, drv == "f")
rwd <- subset(mpg, drv == "r")

ggplot(fwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point()
ggplot(rwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point()
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: first]

The following task is given: Modify the code so that the legend and axes match, without using facetting!

I am able to modify so that the axes match:

```
ggplot(fwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point() + xlim(c(0, 7)) + ylim(c(0, 45))
ggplot(rwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point() + xlim(c(0, 7)) + ylim(c(0, 45))
```

yielding:

[image: two]

But, I'm unable to get the legends to match. This question comes before `scale_colour_manual()` is explained, so I don't think we're supposed to use that.

Any ideas about how to get the legends to match?

Thanks!

Comment: If you add `scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)` it gives the expected output but I am not sure if you are supposed to use that either.

Comment: FYI: I thinkit's better to use `coord_cartesian` rather than `xlim`/`ylim`.  The reason being that `xlim`/`ylim` modify the input data, replacing values which lie outside the limits with NA.  `coord_cartesian()` does not.  This doesn't matter her as you're not doing any interpolation or fitting.  But in other situations it might.  Best not to get into bad habits!

Comment: @RonakShah, I tried `ggplot(fwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point() + xlim(c(0, 7)) + ylim(c(0, 45)) + scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)`, alas it gives the same result.

@Limey thanks for the advice, this is good to know. In fact I may just edit my question to reflect this...